# Matching user input (variable) with list item and printing item

Tags: python

I apologize for the incomprehensible title (I'm new to python). Couldn't write a better one.

Anyway, I have a list, `colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'White']`.

Then I assign variables to these items as `r = Red, b = Blue` and so on.

Now, when I ask the user to select an item using its first letter such as `r`, I want to print `Red`. Similarly if user selects `g`, then print `Green` and so on.

**I want to achieve this without using if statements.** I know this might be very simple but I am a beginner and I tried my level best to search all of the internet to this solution but couldn't find. If possible, please use **f-strings.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing.  What's the list for?  How does the user select options?  Can you post the code you've tried and what you expect the outcome to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the colors in a dictionary instead of a list.

```
colors = {
    'r': 'Red',
    'b': 'Blue',
    ...
}

letter = input('Choose a color letter: ')
print(colors[letter])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map from first letter to full color name

```
def get_color(letter):
    colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'White']
    color_map = {s[0].lower(): s for s in colors}
    return color_map.get(letter, '')

>>> get_color('r')
'Red'
>>> get_color('b')
'Blue'
>>> get_color('x')  # doesn't exist
''
```

Note that this will not handle cases with duplicate first letter (e.g. `"Blue"` and `"Black"`).